# Why is a decimal with trailing zeros not equal to the trimmed decimal?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

If I convert a decimal to a double with and without trailing zeros, I sometimes get a different result. e.g.

```cs
var dec = 0.609_407_4m;
var paddedDec = dec * 1.000_000_000_000_00m;

var doub = (double)dec;
var paddedDoub = (double)paddedDec;

Console.WriteLine(doub - paddedDoub);
// => 1.11022302462516E-16
```

Why is this? Does this imply that the representation of the decimal is different for the two cases?

This seems to be at odds with my understanding that decimals are precise numerical representations.

Comment: Those decimal are precise and comparable while they stay decimals. But internal representation is still different and you left the decimal space with casting. Take a look at the [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Decimal.DecCalc.cs,7cfd5b5e7b92926e) how the casting is done and atleast from the technical side its obvious that you can't expect "precision" after casting.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. I don't expect precision after casting - but I do expect two identical decimals to cast to the same double. Hence I think the key point I've learnt is that adding trailing zeros impacts the internal representation in more ways than just display format, which means the two decimals can no longer be considered identical.

Comment: Yepp a decimal might not be represented exactly in a double. And the slight differences in representation when different scaling is applied to the decimal (even if identical on the surface while being decimal) can lead to a different somewhat inexact double representation when casted.